# Unable to access my local site in another computer. (without LAN)

Tags: apache

I am using Wamp server. Below are the version of PHP, Apache server

-Apache 2.4.9

-Php 5.5.12

-Win7 OS

I have developed a site in my local site(site is running under port 81). I dont have LAN connection with other computers. I need to access that site in another computer for verification. But I unable to access my local site in another computer. I have red different blogs. still my problem is not solved. Below are the changes are made on host files.

1. C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/
   changes made in hosts file

   127.0.0.1 mylocal.site
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra

added below tags in httpd-vhosts file

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/googleoauth/">
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/googleoauth/"
    ServerName mysite.local
</virtualHost>
```

3. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf

included `"Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" in httpd.config file`

After i made these change in my system, my apache server is not started. It displays orange color wamp icon in system tray. Kindly let me know, what mistakes i have did in above configuration work. If i need to access my local site in another computer, what steps I need to follow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access any port from other computer you should have both the systems connected it either in the same LAN (wired/wifi) or different LAN.

But for testing you can connect two computers directly with a [cross-over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_cable) cable. you can access other PCs resources from your PC and vise-versa as if you are in LAN. but this setup limits you to having only two computers connected.

**Note: you need to change network settings in both PCs once connected with cross-over cable and you can find many examples in google.**

Hope this helps.